# 500 internal server error when deploying the project to Vercel

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am a beginner developer and this is my first project using Next.js. I tried to use internal APIs and everything works fine on my local machine without any errors, but when I deployed the project to Vercel, I encountered a 500 internal server error. I've been trying to fix it for a long time, but unfortunately, I couldn't find a solution.If you have any suggestions, please help. Thank you in advance.Here is the link to the repository:https://github.com/KShamil/abb-copy

I configured the environment variables in Vercel, but it didn't help.